# Missing network when cloning Ubuntu in VMware Virtual Machines

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I use VMware to Install Ubuntu 10.04. After cloning an Ubuntu virtual machine,then missing network. Detail as

- The `ifconfig` command does not show the network interface

[image]

and clone Ubuntu virtual machine

[image]

How to fix no network after cloning an Ubuntu VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in http://diigo.com/0r44o. Remove the file /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules. And Ubuntu will regenerate new file.

Answer (score 2):

As per the previous comment udev will cache the MAC address associated with each interface.

If you remove the file /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules, and reboot, you'll find the interface will come up as eth0 and be configured appropriately.

Right now you'll probably find it as eth1 instead.  So your configuration in /etc/network/interfaces will be ignored.

Comment: More on your answer http://www.diigo.com/annotated/5d5c60dcd2ffc7eb5bbe1f2e5f224a33

Answer (score 1):

when cloning virtualmachines, interface name may change to avoid hardware conflicts.
Type

`ifconfig -a`

to list all available network devices, make the necessary changes (obviously the interface name) on your /etc/network/interfaces and bring it up